# Grub can't detect Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

Grub won't detect Windows 7.

Output from `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="AA51-CBCB" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="87996d8d-4fbf-4473-a1fd-7a8bf2ca9136"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="OS" UUID="94D1-4B24" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="080f71e9-2853-472d-b5dc-ba27b91a0550"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="d2352bba-27b2-40f6-95b5-14512559647a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="503dca3f-6f3c-4a17-8ff4-3be7621200c5"
/dev/sda4: UUID="6e046a1b-f5c9-4100-b8a2-b8ec762d68e4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0e281160-0062-4ad8-9ef0-5e344a66b71b"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0603E9765B475CB5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="ac23315c-1b2c-44fb-9946-e72a1a197549"
```

I tried adding a custom entry:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set a3f1ea41fc67a3f1
chainloader +1
}
```

But when I run it, it says that `a3f1ea41fc69a3f1` wasn't found and `hd0,5` wasn't found.

I'm kind of new with Ubuntu, so any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: what you can do is when the system gets to grub *during boot*, stop it there in grub and go to the grub command line. There you should be able to figure out which the correct `set root=` setting is

Comment: @TomášPospíšek How do i get to the command line ?

Comment: please google "grub interactive"